# What is the probability to have the golden grain?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Problem.** A bag contains a *large* number of grains (say, they have a total mass $S$), *exactly* one of which is golden. Adam takes a proportion $k$ of grains from the bag. What is the probability that Adam gets the golden grain?

---

**My Attempt.** If the total number of grains is $N$, and Adam just takes one of them, the probability for him to get the golden grain is trivially $\frac 1N$. But here, $N$ is large, so in some sense $N$ goes to infinity, and we can only consider proportion-wise. The probability that Adam gets the golden grain is equal to the probability that his proportion taken contains the golden grain, but what is this? I am confused and stuck.

---

**Comment.** Just some useful hint can have my green tick. Thank you!

Comment: I feel like the big ambiguity in this problem is "takes a proportion $k$ of grains".  If I'm not thinking too hard, I would interpret $k$ to be an integer, leaving me wondering what it means to "take a proportion 5 of grains".  Would it be better worded as "takes a fraction $p$ of the grain"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability of choosing the golden grain is simply the proportion $k$.

If you want to do more work and approach it combinatorially:

Suppose there are $N$ grains and you choose $m$ of them. There are $N\choose m$ ways to choose $m$ grains, out of which $N-1\choose m-1$ will contain the golden grain. So the probability of getting the golden grain is

$$\frac{N-1\choose m-1}{N\choose m}=\frac{m}{N}=k.$$

Comment: Do you have any intuitive way to understand this? Thank you!

Comment: @IncredibleSimon I am not sure I have much more to offer beyond what I wrote. I think it's fairly intuitive that the proportion of grains you select is the probability you get the golden grain. Take special cases, e.g. if you select one grain the prob. is 1/N; if you select all grains the prob. is 1.

Comment: Visualise a pie chart with $k$ being the proportion of the circle shaded and the remainder unshaded. The golden grain is an unknown point in the circle. The probability that the golden grain point is shaded is just the proportion of the circle that is shaded, which is $k$.